# How to set a unique ID to BarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible set a tag to BarButtonItem, and call it back the tagged BarButtonItem in the action method.

I have tried the code below, but the `println(btnsSend.tag)`, always prints 0.

(`UIBarButtonItem.title` works but I need to set unique id)

```
func configureToolbar() {

    for(var i:Int = 0; i < watchNameArray.count; i++) {

        var newBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
            return UIBarButtonItem(title: watchNameArray[i], style: .Plain, target: self, action: "newButton:");
        }

        toolbarButtonItems += [newBarButtonItem];
        newBarButtonItem.tag = i;            
    }

    thisToolBar.setItems(toolbarButtonItems, animated: true)

}

func newButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var btnsSend:UIBarButtonItem = sender;
    println(btnsSend.tag);
}
```

How can I catch the specific pressed UIBarButtonItem from the action method.

Comment: Your code is missing at least a `}` and probably other important details, because I could not reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `newBarButtonItem` as a... computed local variable? I didn't even know you could do that, so kudos. But it means that every time you access it, you're executing the code in braces. That is, each of these lines creates a new bar button item:

```
// creates a new bar button item and adds it to toolbarButtonItems:
toolbarButtonItems += [newBarButtonItem]
// creates a new bar button item and sets its tag to i:
newBarButtonItem.tag = i
```

The item that you set the tag on is completely separate from the item you add to the array, which is why `tag == 0` for all the items in the array.

Instead, you want to just have `newBarButtonItem` be an instance; then you can customize it and add it to the array. That section of your code should look like this:

```
var newBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: watchNameArray[i], style: .Plain, target: self, action: "newButton:")
newBarButtonItem.tag = i

toolbarButtonItems += [newBarButtonItem]
```